# Install Multiple msi files consecutively

Tags: powershell, batch-file, installation

I have just recently started using (and learning how to) script. I am using Powershell ISE and am trying to create a script that can be run on a new computer to install multiple/various programs. I have the programs in both .exe and .msi and want the programs to install silently, and consecutively. Again I am a beginner, but have put together the script below to get this done. I am trying to find out what variable/command will ensure that the programs install one by one.

```
msiexec.exe /q /i '\\Server\Folder\Applications\msi files\file.msi'
msiexec.exe /q /i '\\Server\Folder\Applications\msi files\file.msi'
msiexec.exe /q /i '\\Server\Folder\Applications\msi files\file.msi'
msiexec.exe /q /i '\\Server\Folder\Applications\msi files\file.msi'
msiexec.exe /q /i '\\Server\Folder\Applications\msi files\file.msi'
msiexec.exe /q /i '\\Server\Folder\Applications\msi files\file.msi'
```

I originally started this as a .bat file, and can run it to install the .exe files just fine, however they all run at the same time. Therefore, I figured creating a script (rather than a .bat file) would be my best bet. Any and all input and or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help Start-Process -Parameter wait` for one way to do that. [*grin*]

Comment: A bat file is a script! You should be using doublequotes, not single quotes. If you open a Command Prompt window and enter `Start /?`, you can see the usage information for one possible thing to try; i.e. `Start` with its `/Wait` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run multiple .msi files all at once if that's what you're wanting. If you want to run them consecutively it would look like this in Powershell:

If it's an msi:

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I ProgramName.msi /quiet'
```

If it's an exe:

```
 Start-Process programname.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I /quiet'
```

And basically the -Wait parameter will wait until the windows installer closes until it proceeds to the next line of code. Some msi's do have different ways of classifying args depending on the developer. Sometimes it's /q, /qn or /quiet.

Answer (score 1):

***Windows Installer***: the **`msiexec.exe`** engine should wait for your installation to complete before it exits. I suspect your command lines are wrong and that is why it looks like they all run and exit simultaneously.

***Sample Command Line***: Maybe try this command line (maybe put in **`MyTest.cmd`** and run):

```dos
msiexec.exe /i MySetup.msi /L*V C:\MyLog.log /qn ADDLOCAL=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress ALLUSERS=1
```

Repeat command line for each MSI you need to install.

***Logging***:The log files should have unique names, obviously. You can [enable logging for all MSI installations](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm) (section **`'Globally for all setups on a machine'`**). Then you will find a new MSI-log file with a random name in the system's **`%TEMP%`** folder after each MSI operation. Sort by change date to find the latest one. To find errors in MSI logs, [try searching for "value 3"](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/).

More information available on request. Please do NOT add your own answer, edit your original question instead. Just add more info, delete or whatever you need. We have versioning so we can find what you delete as well if need be.